# Spring with STS: How to use a project with old dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I've books on Spring programming.  Getting the environment going is proving harder than trying to write code.

My specific example is good for the general case.  I'm trying to load and run the ProSpring3 project provided by the author of the APress Pro Spring 3 book.  I get the latest STS from springsource.org (This is spring-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e4.2-win32-x86_64-installer.exe).  It installs and seems to operate OK.  On my Win 7 PC I set up permissions, env vars, etc. to get files to copy OK and let maven run right.

Now get the project from https://github.com/prospring3/springblog.  It downloads as a ZIP, and I install the code in my projects directory.  STS says that this is some sort of an old project that needs conversion, and I let it.

I try to update the project, or perhaps run it in the server.  Complaints about missing JAR files -- about 80.  The ones it wants are in the .m2 directory.  Here is a sample of the errors:

> Error reading file
>   C:\Users\Jerome.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
>   C:\Users\Jerome.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
>   (The system cannot find the file specified)

So I figure, updating dependencies OUGHT to be easy, because that is why I'm using this stack of software, right?  And perhaps if I change the release to 3.1.1, because that is the version I seem to have, then *something* (Maven?  Roo?) will start automatically fixing things for me.  Not working that way for me, so far.  I think that the directory is missing *every* JAR file.

I went to github.com to find a version of the spring-samples that include the Pet Clinic.  I found one, but *it* insisted on stuff like "3.0.5.RELEASE".

Is it true that whenever I get an updated version of the Spring libraries I'll break about 50-100 lines of each project I write?

Or is there a magic wand somewhere in STS I've yet to discover?